# MKMapView addAnnotations crash

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a random exception that happens randomly when i try to add annotations on a MKMapView.
That crash happens only in this very line of code, and i have other several that add annotations on my map.[image]

In my App annotations are a subclass of NSManagedObject and come straight from a Core Data fetch.
I have tried to debug this error from a long time, but it happens randomly and only in this function.

(I already checked if coordinates are valid, if there is a core data thread problem, and data is not faulting)

@try @catch does not work for this error.

Any ideas?

EDIT: that's the annotation subclass

MapPoint.h

```
@interface MapPoint : NSManagedObject <MKAnnotation>

@property double latitude;
@property double longitude;
@property double  kmINI;
@property double kmFIN;
@property double tag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * altitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * descr;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * note;

-(MKMapItem*)mapItem;

@end
```

MapPoint.m

```
@implementation MapPoint

@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic kmINI;
@dynamic kmFIN;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic category;
@dynamic altitude;
@dynamic descr;
@dynamic identifier;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic note;
@dynamic tag;

#pragma MKAnnotation protocols

-(NSString*)title{

    NSString *title = self.category;
    return title;
}

-(NSString*)subtitle{

    NSString *subtitle = self.name;
    return subtitle;
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude);

}

- (MKMapItem*)mapItem {

    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                              initWithCoordinate:self.coordinate
                              addressDictionary:nil];

    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
    mapItem.name = self.subtitle;

    return mapItem;
}


@end
```

Comment: would you provide code of App annotations class?

Comment: see the question edit

Comment: I spent much time with this problem a while ago. Short answer: never use an NSManagedObject as MKAnnotation. I remember that I found some Apple documentation that one of both doesn’t allow variables to be changed via non API. Don’t find the documentation at the moment. Don’t do it, it can’t be fixed.   https://mobile.twitter.com/gerdcastan/status/1027264991467061249

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on your Target
2) Click Edit Scheme
3) Navigate to Run-> Diagnostics
4) Enable Zombie Objects

[image]

5) Run your application, and try to reproduce the crash.
Debugger will stop on a deallocated object call, and you will stacktrace, so debugging this issue will become much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same question. I debug found both the mapView and the added anootations have values

Enable Zombie Object make no difference.

I guess this is a system bug for iOS.